# Get similarity score between 2 words using Pre trained Bert, Elmo

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding, elmo

I am trying to compare Glove, Fasttext, Bert ,Elmo on basis on similarity between 2 words using pre-trained models of Wiki. Glove and Fasttext had pretrained models which could easily be used with gensim word2vec in python. Does Elmo and Bert have any such models ?

Answer (score 1):

Following is the python code to use the available model of Elmo on Tensorflow and compare similarity between two strings:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf

elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)


def elmo_vectors(x):
  embeddings = elmo(x, signature="default", as_dict=True)["elmo"]

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    # return average of ELMo features
    return sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(embeddings,1))


dist=spatial.distance.cosine(elmo_vectors(["partner"]),elmo_vectors(["vendor"]))
```